# addEventListener not firing when animation ends

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I am using [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) to animate an element. I would like to run some javascript when the animation finishes. For some reason, the following does not work.

```
myElement.addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend", function() {
    //code never runs
}, false);
```

jQuery's `.on()` method works, but I would like to avoid using jQuery:

```
myElement.on("webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend", function() {
    //code runs
});
```

Why is this? And is there another way to detect when the animation finishes  without using jQuery?

Comment: I am not sure you can add multiple events to listen for in the same `addEventListener` call. I think you might have to each of the `animationEnd` listeners individually.

Comment: While it's possible to use multiple **different** events on one listener, vendor prefixed events, style properties, etc. must be used separately.

Comment: @Cristy you may be right. Unfortunately, even when split into multiple listeners the pure javascript approach doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show the HTML? Do you add the listener **before** the transition completes?

Comment: `obj.addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd",....`  // Code for Chrome, Safari and Opera
`obj.addEventListener("animationend", ....`

Comment: @Cristy My mistake, there was another problem in my code. Splitting it up into multiple listeners did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your multiple event types in an array the use `.forEach()` method.

**SNIPPET**

```js
var div = document.querySelector('.animated');


['webkitAnimationEnd', 'animationend'].forEach(function(e) {
  div.addEventListener(e, eventHandler, false);
});

function eventHandler(e) {
  var tgt = e.target;
  tgt.style.color = 'red';
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">


<div class="animated tada">TADA!</div>
```